# Dragging NSTableViewRow only when pressing specific view

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, nstableview

I'm implementing the dragging row in `NSTableView`. Is there any way that only allow user dragging row when they click and move on this view?

The default implementation of `NSTableView` will allow user do `long click` on row then we can move that row around, but that is not I want.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to drag a specific row and not other rows? Or do you want to drag a subview of a row? Or do you want to implement drag & drop reorder? Or something else?

Comment: Hi @Willeke, my purpose is dragging row around this `NSTableView` when holding touch on that `6 dots view` (like reorder row)